# Unable to create a constant value in a linq query

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Running this query:

```
var holderAccounts = db.AccountDetails.Include(p => p.BranchDetail)
               .Where(p => holder.AccountDetails.Any(a => a.Id == p.Id));
```

I get this exception:

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'CodeFirst.AccountDetail'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Relationships are:

```
 AccountHolder 1 to many AccountDetail 1 to 1 BranchDetail
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: holder is an AccountHolder entity's object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try extracting the relevant Ids first:

```
var accountDetailIds = holder.AccountDetails.Select(a => a.Id);
var holderAccounts = db.AccountDetails
    .Include(p => p.BranchDetail)
    .Where(p => accountDetailIds.Contains(p.Id));
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, Any() is not supported. Try this query:

```
var ids = holder.AccountDetails.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
var holderAccounts = db.AccountDetails.Include(p => p.BranchDetail)
           .Where(p => ids.Contains(p.Id));
```

Comment: It looks like it should be `Select` not `SelectMany`.  And it's worth noting that this is only an option if there is a small collection of IDs, if there are a lot this won't work (or won't work well).

Comment: Indeed, most likely it will be a `Select`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is the same as a SQL Where-In Clause. As Jeffery Khan mentioned, I would extract the criteria that you are going to query against and then perform the query in a separate statement. Hopefully this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/03/26/tip-8-writing-where-in-style-queries-using-linq-to-entities.aspx) will help you understand this good practice used to enhance the readability of the query.